# Target container is not a DOM element while rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am getting "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element." while rendering in ReactJS.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
</ApolloProvider>,
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/edit/:id' component={Edit} />
        <Route path='/create' component={Create} />
        <Route path='/show/:id' component={Show} />
    </div>
</Router>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is how my code looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])**

Render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container and return a reference to the component (or returns null for stateless components). [for more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#reference)

there are only two parameters for the render so you can wrap your code in a div

for example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  <Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/edit/:id' component={Edit} />
        <Route path='/create' component={Create} />
        <Route path='/show/:id' component={Show} />
    </div>
 </Router>
</div>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```